# Does PyCharm have Markdown support inside docstrings?

Tags: pycharm, ide, markdown, jetbrains-ide, docstring

I want to insert in docstring markdown part, for example this:

```
[link!](http://google.com)
```

And i want it to show in pop-up window like this (vscode):
[image]

But PyCharm shows it like this:
[image]

Can i have docstring pop-up behavior like in vscode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this answer on PyCharm support](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360009753079-Does-PyCharm-have-Markdown-support-inside-docstrings-), PyCharm, sadly, doesn't have the support of Markdown inside the docstrings.
But reST docstring style supports links, though